# Wygwam + CKeditor + Browse server not showing up after adding image2 plugin

Tags: wygwam, file-uploads, image, ckeditor

I have updated CKeditor and Added the image2 plugin for image caption to work. Now image caption is working fine but the "Browse Server" button to add images from the server is missing.

To manage the images, I am using the Assets plugin and before the update it was setting the path for browse server automatically, but now it's not showing up at all.

Does anyone in here have any idea about this issue? Did anyone get Image caption and Browse image functionality working together? Is there a manual setting that I need to do for this to work?

Comment: "Expresso doesn’t support native EE file selection with the Enhanced Image Plugin, no." via this: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/expresso/viewthread/15426

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here and its worked for me: https://github.com/Natetronn/wygwam-enhanced-image